# How to properly design a backend structure to handle a messaging service?

Tags: javascript, mysql, http, server, backend

So, I am currently working on an project to allow messaging between various devices using REST API's, but I have run into a roadblock as how to handle the requests and retrievals from our backend.

The current structure I have in mind is

- User A writes "Hey, What's up!" to User B in an app (the app doesn't matter, I have all that figured out)
- App then sends message using POST / PUT HTTP requests to our server.
- Backend receives POST / PUT HTTP request
- User B opens the app, creating a GET HTTP request to our server
- Backend sends User B the message (as it is a new message)
- User B retrieves the message
- Database deletes the message as it is no longer needed

Now this is where my experience lacks. I have used MySQL databases before, but is that the best way to store volatile data like this? I have the feeling that there is a better alternative but I do not know it is. What design structure do I use for sending and retrieving requests? Is JavaScript best for this?

Thank you in advance, and sorry if I do not use the correct terms in places as I am inexperienced with this type of backend.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar set up as yours in a previous project of mine.

The only thing I did differently was that I used a JSON file on the server instead of a MySQL server to store the messages.

Through a PHP script on the server that took care of the POST/GET/... requests I constantly updated the file. The requests came from javascript (JQuery) scripts on the client. $.ajax nicely fullfils the requirements here.

Worked fine. Consider though that it may not be the most secure way, so if you want a more secure way to create chat, you may want to look for alternatives. (it was not needed in my setup)